# What is the derivative of $\sin(30^\circ x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

The question is self explanatory. Why is it not $30^\circ \cos(30^\circ x)$? Why has it got to be $\frac{\pi}{6}\cos(30^\circ x)$? Ideally, the result should be a real number without any unit assigned to it.

Comment: $30^{\circ}$ is conform with $360^{\circ}/12$ is conform with $2\pi/12=\pi/6$

Comment: The answer cannot possibly be $\frac\pi6$. Are you really saying that your function has the same derivative everywhere?

Comment: I understand the question as follows: What is the derivative of $\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{6}x)$? And that is $\tfrac{\pi}{6}\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{6}x)$ - by chain rule.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not what you're thinking. I have elaborated more in the comment section of the answer provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\sin$ curve in radians has an amplitude of $1$ and a period of $2\pi$, which is about $6.28$. The $\sin$ curve in degrees has an amplitude of $1$ and a period of $360$, which is much, much longer. As you can imagine, the slope of the curve is much more flattened in degrees, which will make all the derivatives much closer to $0$. You can see how the derivative will indeed depend on the units chosen.

More precisely, if we let $f(x)$ be the $\sin$ of the angle $x$ considered in degrees, then
$$f(x) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{180}x\right) \implies f'(x) = \frac{\pi}{180}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{180}x\right),$$
i.e. with maximum slope of $\frac{\pi}{180} \approx 0.017$, and a minimum slope of $-\frac{\pi}{180}$.

As a side note, this is another argument for radians over degrees. Degrees are an arbitrary unit for measuring angles, splitting up a full rotation into $360$ parts (presumably derived from the base $60$ system favoured by the Mayans?). Radians have the simplest, most natural calculus on their side. The solutions to the differential equation $y'' + y = 0$ are inevitably measured in radians.

So, we can calculate your function's derivative as above:
$$f(x) = \sin(30x^\circ) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}x\right) \implies f'(x) = \frac{\pi}{6}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}x\right).$$

Comment: I think the latter part partially does answer my question. I'm just not very much convinced. My question is, why has it got to be radians and not degree as the answer upon applying the chain rule? Also, is $f'(x)= \frac{\pi}{6} \cos(..) \text{rad}$ or just $\frac{\pi}{6} \cos(..)$? If it's the latter, where does the radian go upon application of the Chain rule?

Comment: I think you need to start thinking of radians as default. With the begrudging exception of writing $\sin(30x^\circ)$, I have only ever used $\sin$ and $\cos$ in terms of radians. If you want to talk about $\sin$ and $\cos$, except with degrees, you must start writing $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{180}x\right)$, and similarly for $\cos$. This is a different function to regular $\sin$ and $\cos$! You can not assume the usual rules of differentiation derived for the regular $\sin$ and $\cos$ apply to these new functions. Also, I think you're too hung up on units; they're just numbers in abstract.